# Supremum and infimum of set $X = \{\frac{xy}{x+y}: x,y \in [0,1]\}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

I found $infX = 0, because \frac{xy}{x+y} \ge 0, \forall x,y \in [0,1]$.

But how can i proof, that $supX = 1/2$ ?

Comment: Do you know a (famous) inequality about the product and the sum of two (or more) numbers?

Comment: What inequality did you mean?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inequality_of_arithmetic_and_geometric_means

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: since $x,y \in [0,1]$ then $xy \in [0,1]$, so $\sqrt{xy} \geq xy$. Further
$$\left(\sqrt{x}-\sqrt{y}\right)^2 \geq 0. $$

Comment: oh, it was so easy, thank you